# Android Studio My name is not displaying in second activity after passing through first Activity

Tags: android-studio

[Main Activity 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxDX7.jpg)

[MAIN ACTIVITY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7gd4.jpg)

Android Studio My name is not displaying in second activity after passing through first Activity

Comment: Change this
``startActivity(intent)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, edittext)
``
to this 
``intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, edittext)
startActivity(intent)``
**Setup your variables first and after start the activity**

Answer (score 0):

In your Main Activity:
Please call intent.putExtra(), before startActivity(). Example:

```
val intent = Intent(this, NewActivity::class.java) 
intent.putExtra("username","Name")
startActivity(intent)
```

And fetch like that (in Main Activity 2)

```
val bundle :Bundle?=intent.extras 
if (bundle!=null){ 
val user_name = bundle.getString("username") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the ['**MainActivity.java**'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7gd4.jpg) you are starting new activity before passing the string into the intent,
just switch the both lines 30 and 31.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, you should putExtra before startActivity. Like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(...);
    intent.putExtra...;
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, create a new Intent:

```
String name="abcdef;
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);    
i.putExtra("key",name);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the MainActivity2, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String name = extras.getString("key");
    //"key" must match that used in the other activity
}
```